# How does magnetic moment transform under Lorentz transformation?

Tags: special-relativity, magnetic-moment

If I have a particle with magnetic moment $\vec{\mu}$ in its rest system $S$, what will its new magnetic moment $\vec{\mu}'$ be if it is moving at speed $\vec{v}$ in a reference system $S'$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The magnetic moment is given by

$$ \mu = \frac{1}{2} \int r \times J \, \mathrm{d}^3 x $$

In order to know how this transforms, we have to re-express it in terms of Lorentz-covariant quantities. For starters we can write $(r \times J)_i = \epsilon_{ijk} r_j J_k $ so

$$ \mu_i = \frac{1}{2} \int \epsilon_{ijk} r_j J_k \, \mathrm{d}^3 x $$

Therefore

\begin{align}
\epsilon_{ilm} \mu_i &= \frac{1}{2} \int \epsilon_{ilm} \epsilon_{ijk} r_j J_k \, \mathrm{d}^3 x \\
&= \int (\delta_{lj} \delta_{mk} - \delta_{lk} \delta_{mj}) r_j J_k \, \mathrm{d}^3 x \\
&= \int r_l J_m - r_m J_l \, \mathrm{d}^3 x
\end{align}

where we have used a common identity for the contraction of two $\epsilon$ symbols.

We could replace $r$ with $x$ (the four-dimensional space-time position) and $J$ with the four-current, but the right-hand side would still not be a Lorentz tensor because the volume element $\mathrm{d}^3 x$ isn't Lorentz invariant. So we must write $\mu_i$ as the volume integral of the magnetization, whereupon

$$ \int \epsilon_{ilm} M_i \, \mathrm{d}^3x = \int r_l J_m - r_m J_l \, \mathrm{d}^3x $$

Finally, we can drop the integration to get a relation between two tensors of order 2 representing volume density. The antisymmetric tensor $\epsilon_{ilm} M_i$ in dimension 3 is replaced by an antisymmetric Lorentz tensor $M^{lm}$ in dimension 4 having $\epsilon_{ilm} M_i$ as the spatial submatrix:

$$ M^{lm} = x^l J^m - x^m J^l $$

By construction, there are 6 nonzero space/space components, of which only three are independent (due to antisymmetry) and those three independent components correspond with the components of the magnetization. It turns out (exercise for the reader) that the mixed (space/time) components of $M$ are the electric polarization. The tensor $M$ is called the polarization-magnetization tensor.

It follows that in order to determine the magnetic dipole moment in another frame, you need to know the electric dipole moment in *this* frame. Just knowing the magnetic dipole moment alone, you don't have enough information to determine the magnetic dipole moment in another frame.

If we assume that the electric dipole moment in the original frame is zero, then, after a Lorentz boost is applied, we find that the magnetization in the frame where the dipole is moving with velocity $v \hat{z}$ is given by $(\gamma \mu_x, \gamma \mu_y, \mu_z)$. The dipole is also length contracted in the z direction by a factor of $\gamma$, so its volume is reduced by a factor of $\gamma$. It follows that the new dipole moment is $(\mu_x, \mu_y, \frac{1}{\gamma} \mu_z)$.

This transformation law is, not surprisingly, the same as that of a pure electric dipole: the boost results in a reduction by a factor of $\gamma$ in the extent of charge separation along the direction of the boost only (leaving the charges themselves and the perpendicular directions unaffected) so the dipole moment in that direction is reduced by a factor of $\gamma$.

Comment: So now we have a disagreement between @mike stone and Brian Bi as to whether the dipole moment is or is not part of a tensor. Can we resolve it? And is my point aboint about the different $t=$ constant hypersurfaces in the two frames relevant?

Comment: @CWPP I don't think there is a disagreement. The tensor simply combines both electric and magnetic dipoles in one object.  Seeing that the choivce of the $t$ surface does not matter involes using the conservation law to show that the difference beween two different choices of hypersurface is zero.

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic moment is part of a skew symmetric 2-tensor $M_{\mu\nu}$. In the rest frame only the space components $M_{ij}= \epsilon_{ijk} \mu_k$ are non zero. In a boosted frame  non-zero electric dipole terms $M_{i0}$ are induced by the Lorentz transformation of the magnetic field.

Comment: The appearance of the electric dipole in the reference frame where the particle is moving provides the clearest interpretation of the spin-orbit interaction in atoms. See my answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/719879/confusion-of-spin-orbit-coupling-in-hydrogen-atom/719907#719907)

Comment: Having thought about it, is what you say exactly true @mike stone? I believe it to be approximately true (hence my earlier comment). But magnetisation and polarization form a skew-symmetric tensor, so that's inconsistent with the dipole moments forming one as well isn't it? I think it's because the integration over a spacelike hypersurface messes up the covariance?

Comment: @CWPP I don't think the integration screws up the tensor properties (in flat space at least) because the  charge and currents are conserved. That's certainly what happens when we obtain  angular momentum as moments of  a conserved energy momentum tensor -- choice of $t=$const does not matter. The dipole moments should work in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

In Mike Schmid's answer the volume element d^3x is not Lorentz invariant. Right? Think dx dy dz. Motion along z contracts dz by 1/gamma but leaves dx and dy alone.

Best to think, more simply, of a current loop with current I and cross-sectional area A in its rest frame. If it is moving at speed v relative to the lab, then in the lab frame the current is a factor 1/gamma smaller due to time dilation. In addition, if the loop is moving edgewise to the relative velocity, so that its mag moment is perpendicular to v, then length contraction reduces its apparent area by another factor of 1/gamma.

The upshot is that a magnetic moment along the direction of relative motion is reduced by a factor of 1/gamma, but a magnetic moment perpendicular to the direction of motion is reduced by a factor 1/gamma squared.

Interestingly, if the magnetic moment were due to a pair of actual magnetic monopoles, and assuming that magnetic charge is invariant, then the only effect would be Lorentz contraction, which reduces the dipole moment by 1/gamma if along the velocity but leaves it unchanged perpendicular to the velocity.