# What is the covariant version of the dipole moment?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, dipole-moment

Magnetic dipoles in a rest frame behave as a mixture of dielectric dipoles and magnetic dipoles in another moving frame. However this is sometimes controversial due to Mansuripur's paradox (see Griffiths 2013 article about it). According to a deleted answer in another question, there is a covariant version of multipole expansion. What does it look like and what is the additional 0th component of the dipole moment? Does it still lead to definitional issues?

Note that Wikipedia and Griffiths article talk about a polarization-magnetization tensor but not one for electric-magnetic dipole.

Comment: *According to this question's answer…* I don’t see an answer for the question you linked to. Has it been deleted?

Comment: @Ghoster yes it was removed, I do not know why.

Comment: I suspect that the linked answer was ChatGPT-generated. It seemed like nonsense: I do not believe you can construct a covariant quadrupole moment tensor of order 2 (considering that the dipole moment already requires a tensor of order 2 in order to be made covariant) and if it were a real answer then surely the author would have given a better explanation of how such an object is to be defined.

Comment: @BrianBi I do not know if it was automated, but certainly it did not have any sources

Comment: Can members with enough rep still see the deleted answer? If not, doesn’t that mean it was deleted by a moderator? (In which case it was probably believed to be generated.)

Comment: @Ghoster I can still see it. It was indeed deleted by a moderator and it does seem ChatGPT generated. There are no references and no equation (although $Q^{\mu\nu}$ occurs twice)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot simply add a $0^\text{th}$ component to the
dipole moment to get a covariant $4$-vector.
<s>Instead you need to put the [electric dipole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_dipole_moment)
$\vec{p}$ and the [magnetic dipole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole) $\vec{m}$
together into a covariant $4$-tensor.</s>

Thanks to all the comments below I realized it is actually
more complicated than I thought before.

The electric dipole moment $\vec{p}$ and the magnetic dipole moment
$\vec{m}$ cannot directly be put together to form something covariant.
But you can do it with the corresponding densities
(polarization $\vec{P}$ and magnetization $\vec{M}$)
which are defined by the volume integrals
$$\vec{p}=\int \vec{P}\ d^3r$$
$$\vec{m}=\int \vec{M}\ d^3r$$

Polarization $\vec{P}$ and magnetization $\vec{M}$
can be put together to form a covariant $4$-tensor.
See [Covariant formulation of classical electromagnetism - Magnetization-polarization tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism#Magnetization%E2%80%93polarization_tensor)
or Griffiths' article [Manuripur's Paradox](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.0732) (eq. 20).
Its contravariant components are
$$M^{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}
 0    &  cP_x &  cP_y &  cP_z \\
-cP_x &  0    & -M_z  &  M_y  \\
-cP_y &  M_z  &  0    & -M_x  \\
-cP_z & -M_y  &  M_x  & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

(This is quite similar to how you put the electric field
$\vec{E}$ and the magnetic field $\vec{B}$ into the
[Faraday tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor#Relationship_with_the_classical_fields) $F^{\mu\nu}$.)

See also the related question [How does magnetic moment transform
under Lorentz transformation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/724143/how-does-magnetic-moment-transform-under-lorentz-transformation) and its answers.

Comment: Neat! Does this tensor have a common name?

Comment: @knzhou I haven't seen a catchy name yet.

Comment: I validated this answer as it was what I was looking for. However, I think this marvelous tensor does not solve the problems with Mansuripur's paradoxes, do you got anything on that?

Comment: @Mauricio Sorry, I dont know anything about it, although a quick search on
["mansuripur paradox"](https://www.google.com/search?q=mansuripur+paradox)
found quite a few articles.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch oops I think I just have forgotten what was there on those articles. The tensor is right there in Griffiths's article...

Comment: @Mauricio *the problems with Mansuripur's paradoxes* Doesn’t the Griffiths paper explain away all the problems? There *is* no paradox.

Comment: It's actually only tensorial when $m$ and $p$ are the *densities* of the magnetic dipole moment and electric dipole moment, respectively. It's then known as the polarization-magnetization tensor.

Comment: @Ghoster there are all kind of paradoxes with electromagnetism in matter and relativity, related to hidden momentum. While not a paradoxes per se (you can take a look at the two possibilities by Griffiths), I was expecting some additional insight.

Comment: @BrianBi this is important, does that mean that the tensor up here is not covariant?

Comment: @Mauricio *I was expecting some additional insight.* Why? What about Griffiths’ resolution of the “paradox” is insufficient?

Comment: @Ghoster as the topic is still niche you see debates from time to time. See for example Redfern 2020 arxiv. I am no expert on this I just know that when transforming dipoles I have to double check for the right transformation...

Comment: Here is Wikipedia’s discussion of the [magnetization-polarization tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism#Magnetization–polarization_tensor). I agree with @BrianBi.

Comment: @Ghoster you agree on the name or something else?

Comment: @Mauricio That the moment densities form a tensor. I don’t think the moments do. I’ve removed my upvote.

Comment: Removing validation on question until this is clarified

Comment: I think it is clear that $\mathbf P$ and $\mathbf M$ have to transform like $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B$ (i.e., as components of a Lorentz tensor) since they appear additively in the Wikipedia section above the one I linked to. A spatial volume element is not Lorentz-invariant. So I don’t see how $\mathbf p$ and $\mathbf m$ could be components of a Lorentz-covariant tensor.

Comment: Hmmm… [Mike Stone’s comments](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/724143/how-does-magnetic-moment-transform-under-lorentz-transformation) on his answer are making me think I might be wrong. CWPP raised my objection and Mike swatted it down. I’m restoring my upvote.

Comment: @Mauricio It would be great to get an answer that makes it completely clear that the $M_{\mu\nu}$ here is really a tensor.

Comment: Thanks to all the comments above, I updated my answer.