# Can a Foldy–Wouthuysen transformation of Dirac equation in an EM field highlight Thomas interaction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, dirac-equation, spin-orbit

Based on a previous question [Is the Thomas precession a correction to a Lorentz transformation or an interaction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/755565/is-the-thomas-precession-a-correction-to-a-lorentz-transformation-or-an-interact) , Thomas precession can be seen as an additional weakly relativistic interaction to the fine structure, in such a way that it reduces the value of the "bare" spin-orbit coupling.

Following the [Foldy-Wouthuysen transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foldy%E2%80%93Wouthuysen_transformation), Schrödinger's equation with weakly relativistic corrections can be recovered from Dirac's equation in the presence of electromagnetic (EM) fields. However it is hard to notice if such a derivation distinguishes bare spin-orbit (SO) coupling from Thomas interaction (which is just -1/2 the bare SO).

Is it possible to determine which terms are "bare" spin-orbit and which are Thomas interaction from a weakly relativistic development? Or their separation is rather a matter of taste?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is No it is not possible directly from the FW transformation. The Dirac equation is fully relativistic and encodes the values $g=2$, and thus the transformation collects all terms of order $\alpha^2$. Thus the various terms are only distinguished by their dependence on $\bf E$ and $\bf B$. The Thomas term comes together with the magnetic spin orbit term, and they can only be separated by observing that the spin-orbit term has an unexpected size.

Obviously if we start including the $(g-2)$ corrections then it becomes more obvious that the spin-orbit term can be split into two parts.

Because the Thomas precession depends on $\bf v\times\bf a$ and only on $\bf E$ when that is the origin of the acceleration, the separation is clearer when the acceleration is not due to $\bf E$. In Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics this point is made and suggested as the reason for the inverted spin-orbit term in nuclei where the acceleration is due to the strong force and this dominates the electromagnetic spin-orbit term.

Comment: Would adding a Pauli style coupling make it more obvious to see that there is a g-2 term?